# The AFT and PH model

Tags: survival, sampling, proportional-hazards, accelerated-failure-time

According to the following - https://dylanspicker.com/courses/STAT437/content/041%20+%20044.%20Lecture%20Notes.pdf
the PH and AFT models are equivalent for Weibull distribution.

Does this implies the event-time should be distributed similarly? The following code seems to contradict it. What am I missing?

```
n       <- 100000
rho     <- 2 # scale of h_0 that follow weibull (lambda)
k       <- 3 # shape of h_0 that follows weibull (v)
x       <- rnorm(n) 

## AFT 
t_aft <- exp(log(rho) + x + 1 / k * rweibull(n, scale=rho, shape=k))

## PH 
# sampling is done based on bender 2003
t_ph <- (1 / rho) * (-log(runif(n)) * exp(k * x))^(1 / k) 

plot(density(t_ph))
lines(density(t_aft), col = 'red')
```